# How to Run a JMeter Script as a Windows Cron Job

Tags: cron, jmeter, cron-task

I am in need of scheduling my test such that my JMeter script automatically runs without I having to manually execute it daily. This can be accomplished via a Windows cron job but I do not know how to configure the JMeter script to run as a Windows cron job. Normally I use the command "jmeter -n -t path\filename.jmx -l path\log.csv" to execute my JMeter script via the command line so I assume if I can make this command run as a cron job it should solve the problem theoretically. So I sincerely appreciate if someone could provide the steps and details to accomplish this, thanks.

Comment: Write your jmeter command I a batch file and schedule the batch script to run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using [Windows Task Scheduler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) like

1. Open Task Scheduler
2. Click `Action -> Create Task`
3. On "General" tab provide name
4. On "Triggers" tab provide when you would like to run it
5. On "Actions" tab create a new action like:

   - Program: `c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe`
   - Arguments: `/c c:\jmeter\bin\jmeter.bat -n -t c:\jmeter\extras\Test.jmx -l c:\jmeter\bin\Test_%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%.jtl`

     [image: JMeter Windows Scheduled Task]

Change JMeter and .jmx script location to match your details.

Each time your task runs the file with current date should appear in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation like `Test_20180514.jtl` for today

Just in case here is exported task:

```
﻿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.2" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>2018-05-14T07:50:02.7061254</Date>
    <Author>aldan\anonymous</Author>
    <URI>\JMeter</URI>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers />
  <Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <UserId>S-1-5-21-2873627350-121124179-3591956082-1001</UserId>
      <LogonType>InteractiveToken</LogonType>
      <RunLevel>LeastPrivilege</RunLevel>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>true</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>true</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>false</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <IdleSettings>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <WakeToRun>false</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT72H</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe</Command>
      <Arguments>/c c:\jmeter\bin\jmeter.bat -n -t c:\jmeter\extras\Test.jmx -l c:\jmeter\bin\Test_%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%.jtl</Arguments>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```

---

Be aware that easier option could be using [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/) to orchestrate your builds, this way you will have history, metrics, conditional failure criteria and performance trend charts.

[image: Jenkins Performance Trend]

See [Continuous Integration 101: How to Run JMeter With Jenkins](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/continuous-integration-101-how-run-jmeter-jenkins) article for more information regarding adding performance tests under Jenkins control

Comment: Woow thanks a lot Dmitri, your answer was very detailed and was very helpful. Thanks a lot for your kind assistance I sincerely appreciate it.